# NFT Listing for Sale on NEAR Marketplace

Tags: nearprotocol, near

On the basis of this NFT example `https://github.com/near-examples/nft-tutorial/`, I have created two contracts, lets say:

```
dd-token-v1.testnet - NFT Token Contract (Will allow anyone to mint NFTs)

dd-marketplace-v2.testnet - NFT Marketplace Contract
```

I created a Front end project to mint and sell NFTs.
I have minted few NFTs on my NFT Token Contract by generating a mint link using `/sign_url` rest api. Its integrated in FE and working fine. And I can see those minted NFTs on my testnet wallet.
(In the below attachment, you can see a test request to mint an NFT)

[image]

Now I'm working on listing/sale integration part. In the below attachment, you can see NFT Listing Transaction of paras platform on Near's mainnet wallet.
[image]

I want to generate the same type of transaction link using `/sign_url` to list my minted NFTs for sale on `testnet` network. But I don't know what to send in that request payload to generate NFT listing link. Please help me to integrate sales part for my FE project.

`/sign_url` Rest API Details:
[image]

Thank you.